# Bind row added or removed from jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

After creation of jqgrid.

In another jquery method I wanna bind event to check if row is added or removed from the jqgrid.

I wanna keep record of changes in the existing grids.
How I can do that?

something like this

```
   $(grid).bind('jqGridRowAdded', function () {
        alert('hello');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's important to know which method will be used to add the row. The most common case is the usage of `addRowData` method either directly or indirectly. So you should use `jqGridAfterInsertRow` instead of non-existing event `jqGridRowAdded`. The short description of supported events you will find in [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aevents#list_of_triggered_events_new_in_v4.3.2). The parameters of the events are not described currently in the documentation. So I recommend you to find parameters in the source code of jqGrid (see [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.1/js/grid.base.js#L2996) for example).